How to type field and form from the Field Render method in Formik
I'm new to Typescript and Formik. I've been working through numerous tutorials on Formik and found a solution to use custom inputs using Formik. I'm specifically using the Field component using the render method. Per the documentation the Field render props are an object containing field and form. It looks something like this..
<Field name={name}>
  {
    ({field,form}) => { // does formik have a type definition for these ? 
    return(..custom input)
   }
  }
</Field>

I found something in Formik types called FieldInputProps but that doesn't seem to appease Typescript.
